# How to find the index of a Powerpoint Shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a VBA script to copy+paste charts from an Excel worksheet to an existing Powerpoint presentation as Picture.

So far I was successful to do the copy-paste as Picture, but failed to change the size of the pasted picture. I believe the pasted picture is a shape, so I'm trying to do something like:

```
 For Each iChart In arrChart
        xlWorkBook.Worksheets("PPT").ChartObjects(iChart).CopyPicture
        ActivePresentation.Slides(iCurrSlide).Shapes.Paste
        'Reshape
        ActivePresentation.Slides(iCurrSlide).Select
            With ActivePresentation.Slides(iCurrSlide).Shapes.Item(5)
                .Select
                .Height = ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight
                .Width = ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
                .Left = 0
                .Top = 0
            End With
        iCurrSlide = iCurrSlide + 1
Next iChart
```

However I seem to get the wrong index, so I'm wondering if there is a way to capture the index of the picture (as a shape)? I have my hands tied as I cannot name the picture (if I'm to name each picture pasted, I'd rather throw the script into garbage can and simply paste manually), and I cannot change anything about the pptx and xlsx.

Comment: Can you share your copy-paste code?

Comment: Doesn't the last shape created have the max. index?

Comment: Naming the shape is simple to do with code so why is this a problem?  In fact, I always try to do this for the very reason that it makes it easy to track back to a specific item. If you set up a loop to copy them you can simply code to add the items.count onto a generic name e.g. pic1, pic2 or use a counter variable.

Comment: @ashleedawg Yeah sure, I edited the post. Thank you!

Comment: @TimWilliams You are right! I didn't think about that.

Answer (score -2):

Avoid selecting anything unless it's absolutely necessary, which it seldom is.
Assuming this is happening in VBA within PPT:

```
Dim oSh as Shape

For Each iChart In arrChart
        xlWorkBook.Worksheets("PPT").ChartObjects(iChart).CopyPicture

        ' Set a reference to the just-pasted shape
        Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(iCurrSlide).Shapes.Paste(1)

        'Reshape

        ' You don't need this:
        ' ActivePresentation.Slides(iCurrSlide).Select
            ' With ActivePresentation.Slides(iCurrSlide).Shapes.Item(5)
            With oSh
                ' No need to select it as long as you've got a reference to it:
                '.Select

                ' I'd use ActivePresentation.PageSetup here but it may not matter
                .Height = ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight
                .Width = ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
                .Left = 0
                .Top = 0
            End With    ' oSh
        iCurrSlide = iCurrSlide + 1
Next iChart
```

Comment: Question was simple, how to find the index of a shape in powerpoint. For example, To group a shape you need to get the shaperange from selection, and there are no alternatives.